# cannot create a CIImage

Tags: ios, ciimage

I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong here, but for some reason, no matter how I try, I cannot create a CIImage

```
UIImage *origImage  = [[UIImage alloc] init];
origImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

imageName = [imageName substringToIndex:[imageName length]-4];
NSURL *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:imageName withExtension:@"jpg"];

NSLog(@"the path is %@", path1);
NSLog(@"the inputImage is %@", imageName);

CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:origImage.CGImage];
CIImage *inputImage1 = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:_originalImage];
CIImage *inputA = [[CIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:path1];
CIImage *empty = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:origImage];
```

A breakpoint at the end of this code shows a UIImage, a string and a url, all of which are as expected.
The header includes CoreImage.h, as well as UIKit. _originalImage is a UIImage property, which is assigned earlier.

Stumped on this for a few days, any help really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you getting? Null references in the CIImages?

Comment: yes - all the CIImages are nil

Comment: I was thinking it could be I've a corrupt CoreImage header, but it works on another project!

Answer (score 0):

Using your code I get all 4 CIImages, is it possible that there is something with your jpg file?

Comment: Hi CarouselMin, I had also tested this theory in another project, with the same images, but they worked well there. Answer was in the LLVM code generation settings, as detailed below.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this via the project settings.
I have found that if I had set the optimisation level of the Apple LLVM 6.0 Code Generation to something other than None [-00], then none of these images formed.
however, without the optimisation, it works as expected.
Not sure why, but not complaining.